# JQuery DatePicker not showing in textbox when textbox is enabled

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a set of controls, which sit inside an ajax update panel, and these controls are enabled via the user ticking a checkbox. One of these controls is a textbox, which uses the JQuery Datepicker to populate the textbox with a date. The problem I am seeing is when the textbox is enabled, and you click on the textbox the datepicker is not showing. The only way I can get the datepicker to show up is after the validator is fixed to show that no date has been set.

There is no magic code. If the checkbox is ticked then txtDate.enabled = true.

Has anyone come across this problem before? If so, how was it solved?

Thanks

Comment: Are you registering your datepicker in `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest` event?

Comment: No. I am using datepicker on other textboxes else where in my user control, which are not inside an updatepanel, and theses work as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, after UpdatePanel reload, the HTML content is being recreated and the datepicker event bind gets lost.

Try registering your datepicker this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(evt, args) {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
});
</script>
```

Checkout this posts as well: [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072713/using-jquery-ui-datepicker-inside-updatepanel) and [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520645/jquery-datepicker-ms-ajax-updatepanel-doesnt-work-after-post-back)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

//this function will fire after the textbox is posted back.

```
function pageLoad(sender,args){
  $(".datepicker").datepicker();
}
```

Also [Read This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1735774.aspx/1)